# Unable to Save Edited Comments in Adobe Acrobat - "Dictionary Keys Must Be Direct Name Objects" Error (LaTeX PDF)

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I'm facing an issue with saving edits to comments in Adobe Acrobat. Here's the situation:

- I created a document using LaTeX (compiler unknown, possibly Overleaf or MikTeX locally).
- I potentially used GhostScript to reduce the file size.
- I used Adobe Acrobat to leave comments during a meeting and saved the PDF successfully.
- Now, I'm trying to modify some of the comments by marking them as complete, but I'm unable to save the changes.

When attempting to save, I receive the following error message:

[image]

> "The document could not be saved. There was a problem reading this document (135)."

Pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + OK reveals a further message:

[image]

> "Dictionary keys must be direct name objects."

Does anyone have any suggestions on resolving this issue and saving the edited comments in Adobe Acrobat? I would greatly appreciate any insights into the "Dictionary keys must be direct name objects" error in this context.

**Additional Information:**

- I'm unsure about the specific LaTeX compiler used (potentially Overleaf or MikTeX).
- GhostScript might have been involved in reducing the file size, but I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**P.S.** I also posted the question [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/unable-to-save-edited-comments-in-adobe-acrobat-quot-dictionary-keys-must-be-direct-name-objects/m-p/14473525#M106684).

Comment: If you used Ghostscript to produce the PDF file then it will have the /Producer key set to Ghostscript, if it isn't, then it's not a Ghostscript-produced PDF. As K J says, we'd need to see the file to comment further.

Comment: @KenS how can I check the "/Producer" key?

Comment: @KJ, the PDF file is unpublished academic work, so I am not allowed to share it outside the confidential team.

Comment: @KenS I check the `/Producer` key using `exiftool -Producer "path\to\your\file.pdf"` and got `pdfTeX-1.40.25`

Comment: trying with `pdftk "yourfile.pdf" dump_data output metadata.txt` I get `macOS Version 12.7.3 (Build 21H1015) Quartz PDFContext, AppendMode 1.1` for the `Producer` key!

Comment: @KJ Admittedly, I did open the file on my Mac and tried to save it there, but it failed as well. But now I am on Windows.

Comment: @KJ I ran the command `type "yourfile.pdf" | findstr /C:"%%EOF"` and got two `%%EOF` results. Is that what I should expect?

Comment: @KJ I used [this script](https://pastebin.com/5gfFf3kL) to trim everything after the last occurrence of `%%EOF` but it led to `There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.`